# Writing data to excel cells erase existing cells I don't touch

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

My application reads data from an excel file with 9 columns, does some work and, if some conditions are met, writes data in the 9th column of the current row. This part works fine. The problem is that everything I didn't write gets erased, even other worksheets in the file.

Here's the only part of my code that writes to the file.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;[...]


 Dictionary<int, string> newlines = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 //excel reader reads the file, iterates the rows,
 //check up the conditions, add pairs to newlines when needed  

 m_excelWriter = new ExcelWriter();    
 m_excelWriter.Open(FilePath);

 foreach (var item in newlines)
 {
    m_excelWriter.WriteLine(item.Value, item.Key);
 }
 m_excelWriter.Close();


public void WriteLine(string Value, int RowNumber)
{
   m_Worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 8] = Value;
   //both ways have the problem
   //((Range)m_Worksheet.Cells[RowNumber, 8]).Value2 = Value;
}
```

Here Nevyn. I didn't write this part though.

**EDIT: LOOKS LIKE I CAN'T READ**
after posting this for you, I realised the (quite obvious) problem

```
 public void Open(string FilePath)
    {
        // Open Excel :
        Process[] ExcelProcessesBefore = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
        this.m_Application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Process[] ExcelProcessesAfter = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
        this.m_ProcessId = this.GetProcessId(ExcelProcessesBefore, ExcelProcessesAfter);
        this.m_Application.DisplayAlerts = false;

        // Open the worksheet :
        this.m_Workbook = this.m_Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        this.m_Workbook.SaveAs(FilePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                               Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing,
                               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

         m_Worksheet = (_Worksheet)m_Workbook.Worksheets[0];

    }
```

Comment: What does your FileOpen code look like?  Im looking specifically for the application initialization and the app.Workbooks.Open(...) command

Comment: Ok, that code looks like it uses an already opened instance of EXCEL, and adds a completely blank new workbook to it, then saves it to the path passed into the method.  if the Workbook you read the data from is already open you shouldn't need to re-call "Open" on it, but if its closed then this method you just showed me will never work, it will always erase the original by overwriting it.

Comment: I saw the problem a soon as I reviewed my post, sorry lol.

Comment: As I have often found with my own code....sometimes you just need someone to point out the elephant in the room :-)  Enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to find that assigning the cell value directly like that doesn't work as well as using the built in functionality to set the value does.

In my code I use this line to set a cell value

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[row, ccol]).Value2 = cellVal;
```

Re-cast the cell to a Range, then set the range `Value2` setting.  I dont know if this will fix the problem you are having or not though.

Comment: It may have something to do with which file you open or how you are opening it...can you post some of your other processing code like the App.Workbooks.Open call.  Also, verify to make sure you are actually getting the correct file and not just opening a blank new workbook and then overwriting the existing file when you re-save it